# Row color for jquery-bootgrid

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

I am working with bootgrid. I want the row color to be highlighted based on the specific condition. How do i do it??

```
 <script type="text/javascript">         
          $(document).ready(function () {
          //Basic Example
            $("#data-table-command").bootgrid({

               css: {
                  icon: 'md icon',
                  iconColumns: 'md-view-module',
                  iconDown: 'md-expand-more',
                  iconRefresh: 'md-refresh',
                  iconUp: 'md-expand-less'
               },

        formatters: {
            "commands": function (column, row) {

                return "<a class=\"btn btn-success \"   data-row-id=\"" +     row.id + "\" href=/Ticket/ViewTicket?id=" + row.id + "> <span class=\"md md-  pageview\"></span> View </a>" + "" + "\&nbsp;" + "\&nbsp;" +
                    "<a class=\"btn btn-warning \"   data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\" href=/Ticket/Close?id=" + row.id + "> <span class=\"md md-close\"></span> Close </a>" + "" + "\&nbsp;" + "\&nbsp;";

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is implemented in version 1.2.0 which is currently not released, because of lacking documentation, but will be very shortly.

Three ways to grab the new version:

1. From NuGet via `Install-Package jQuery.Bootgrid -Pre`
2. From NPM via `npm install jquery-bootgrid@1.2.0-rc`
3. From the github branch [fixes-and-features](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-bootgrid/tree/fixes-and-features)

For more information on how it works see [issue 72](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-bootgrid/issues/72) on github.

Comment: This works, but the "status" concept took a while for me to assimilate. If it helps anyone else, what this really is is a value which represents a "row class". The "statusMapping" thing maps from the value to the class you want it to put on the row.